# Ionic - ld: framework not found UserNotifications

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, phonegap-pushplugin

I created a ionic project and tried to implement push notification using https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/

`ionic build ios` run without any issue.

But when I tried to emulate the app on IOS using `ionic emulate iOS` it fails with following error.

```
ld: framework not found UserNotifications
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)



** BUILD FAILED **



The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/emulator/JustBook\ Salon.app/JustBook\ Salon normal i386
(1 failure)
```

I used administrator permissions to run those command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS 10 introduces the new [UserNotifications framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications). I would assume the plugins used in this project have been updated to support/include it which means you need to build with XCode 8, which includes the iOS 10 SDK containing the UserNotifications framework. Building with XCode 7 will result in the observed error.

Note that at this time, Cloud-based Cordova build services such as Phonegap Build, Intel SDK and Ionic Cloud are still using XCode 7.

Answer (score 2):

I've been encountering this issue as well on XCode.

> ld: framework not found UserNotifications
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

DaveAlden provides an explanation as to why this happens.

## How to still build with XCode 7

Go through your project, find `UserNotifications`, and remove it.

1. Press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
2. Find text matching `UserNotifications`. The `.xcconfig` files should show up in the occurrences.
3. In the files where it occurred, remove the `-framework "UserNotifications"` from the command line parameters for each of the occurrences.
4. Save the `.xcconfig` file.
5. Build and run.

So far, I don't have a way to prevent Pods from adding these lines to the project.

Comment: I updated my xcode to version 8 and built it successfully. Thanks for the answer. This will help to someone.